# How to put an image on top of another image in a PdfPCell (iTextSharp)?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, itext

I have two images (`iTextSharp.text.Image`) and I want to place them directly on top of each other in a `PdfPCell`. One of the images has transparency and should be placed top most.

I have tried the following:

```
imgOpaque.Alignment = Image.UNDERLYING;
imgOpaque.SetAbsolutePosition(10f, 10f);
imgTransparent.SetAbsolutePosition(10f, 10f);

var cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.AddElement(imgOpaque);
cell.AddElement(imgTransparent);
table.AddCell(cell);
```

But this results in the second image being positioned after the first - and not on top.

**How do I get the two images on top of each other?**

*iTextSharp version is 5.4.3.*

Answer (score 0):

Implement `IPdfPCellEvent` for "bottom" image.

> ```
> public class CellBackgroundImage : IPdfPCellEvent {
>     private Image _background;
>     public void SetImage(string path)  {
>         _background = Image.GetInstance(path);
>     }
>     public void CellLayout(
>         PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rectangle, PdfContentByte[] pcb) 
>     {
>         PdfContentByte cb = pcb[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
>         cb.AddImage(_background, 
>             rectangle.Width, 0, 0, rectangle.Height
>            ,rectangle.Left, rectangle.Bottom
>         );
>     }
> }
> ```

Create `PdfPCell`, set it's `CellEvent` property, and add "top" image.

> ```
> using (Document document = new Document()) {
>     PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream); // any Stream object
>     document.Open();
>     PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
>     CellBackgroundImage cbi = new CellBackgroundImage();
>     cbi.SetImage(imageBottomPath);
>     Image imageTop = Image.GetInstance(imageTopPath);
>     PdfPCell imageCell = new PdfPCell();
>     imageCell.CellEvent = cbi;
>     imageCell.AddElement(imageTop);
>     table.AddCell(imageCell);
>     document.Add(table);
> }
> ```